# Route preference ignored

Tags: networking

I have a Raspberry Pi with two network interfaces on raspbian (bullseye). A wifi connected to internet (wlan0) and an ethernet interface connected to some local network (eth0).

When trying to access the internet (for example doing `apt update`) linux is systematically trying to go through eth0 (192.168.0.10).

Note that I have configured dhcpcd on eth0:

```
interface eth0
nogateway
static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24
metric 500
```

```
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
[... cut ...]
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether a1:36:ea:34:12:fc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.10/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9129:9d0e:4f4b:34d3/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether de:ad:be:e:ff:42 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.71/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlan0
       valid_lft 85437sec preferred_lft 74637sec
    inet6 2a02:8428:32a2:3501:b81:667b:1484:2004/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 604557sec preferred_lft 604557sec
    inet6 fe80::84d0:1440:d0f3:a758/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Looking at `route -n`, wlan0 seems better positioned:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     500    0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 wlan0
```

Even when I turn the eth0 down:

```
sudo ip link set eth0 down
```

It still tries (and fails) to connect to the internet.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I did not mentioned in my question and which was the reason of failure is the use of `dnsmasq`.

So `dhcpcd` would configure a DHCP client for `eth0` which would set the address of the interface to a static value. And then `dnsmasq` would, through that interface, act as a DHCP server for the camera. However, the principal job of `dnsmasq` is to be a DNS server. So by default, dnsmasq would mess up the DNS resolutions. So, in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`, I just added:

```
port=0
```

Do disable the DNS server and now request go through `wlan0` for internet.

Comment: So, "_When trying to access the internet (for example doing apt update) linux is systematically trying to go through eth0 (192.168.0.10)_" is incorrect?

Comment: I don't think this is incorrect.

Comment: Your answer seems to be mixing up the two principal services of `dnsmasq` - DHCP service and DNS service. Either can be switched on or off in `dnsmasq` independently

Comment: Yes @roaima, you are right, that was the source of my problem. By disabling the DNS service from dnsmasq my problem was resolved.